# how can I simplify BoWs?

Tags: nlp

I'm trying to apply some binary text classification but I don't feel that having millions of >1k length vectors is a good idea. So, which alternatives are there for the basic BOW model?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are quite a few different approaches, based on what exactly you are aiming for in your prediction task (processing speed over accuracy, variance in your text data distribution, etc.).
Without any further information on your current implementation, I think the following avenues offer ways for improvement in your approach:

- **Using sparse data representations**. This might be a very obvious point, but choosing the right data structure to represent your input vectors can already save you a great deal of pain. Sklearn offers a variety of options, and detail them in their [great user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#the-bag-of-words-representation). Specifically, I would point out that you could either use `scipy.sparse` matrices, or alternatively represent something with sklearn's [`DictVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer).
- **Limit your vocabulary**. There might be some words that you can easily ignore when building your BoW representation. I'm again assuming that you're working with some implementation similar to sklearn's [`CountVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html), which already offers a great number of possibilities. The most obvious option are stopwords, which can simply be dropped from your vocabulary entirely, but of course you can also limit it further by using pre-processing steps such as lemmatization/stemming, lowercasing, etc. `CountVectorizer` specifically also allows you to control the minimum and maximum **document frequency** (don't confuse this with corpus frequency), which again should limit the size of your vocabulary.